# Flutter - Adding text next to an image which is using gesture detector

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to add text, next to an image which is using `GestureDetector` to open the URL. I'm attaching an image below for reference so it's easier to understand. [image]

Here is the code for this class:

```
class SocialMedia extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Social Media"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new AssetImage('images/affedbackground.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
//        child: Padding(
//          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 110.0, 8.0, 20.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: _launchURLInstagram,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'images/instagram.png',
                  // On click should redirect to an URL
                  width: 32.0,
                  height: 32.0,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: _launchURLFacebook,
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/facebook.png', // On click should redirect to an URL
                width: 32.0,
                height: 32.0,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
//      ),
    );
  }

  _launchURLInstagram() async {
    const url =
        'https://instagram.com/';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  _launchURLFacebook() async {
    const url = 'https://www.facebook.com/';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to add some text below the image and make this text clickable too - is it correct?

Comment: I don't need the text to necessarily be clickable but don't mind if it is, I need the text to be beside on the left or right of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Row` instead of `Image`:

```
GestureDetector(
    child: Row(
        children[
          Text('...'),
          Image.asset(
              'images/instagram.png'...
            ),
          ]
        ),
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: missing a "Colon" : after "children"